# GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(context) crashing, Receiver not registered

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How should I call GCMRegistrar.onDestroy? Currently my main activity contains this:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And after doing a registration or unregistration and then killing the main activity I am getting this:

```
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.test.android/com.test.android.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@40673a10
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3090)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3155)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:132)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1071)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@40673a10
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:634)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:880)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.content.Contexttester.unregisterReceiver(Contexttester.java:331)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(GCMRegistrar.java:249)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at com.test.android.activities.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:407)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
08-13 15:43:56.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     ... 11 more
```

Edit, from the mainfest:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.PushReceiver"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <category android:name="com.test.android" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".services.PushService" />
```

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: It seems that problem is stems from GCMBroadcastReceiver. If you show manifest file i will try to help.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think I solved it. When doing GCMRegistar.register(context), I used two different contexts. Switch to using getApplicationContext() instead of this worked fine.

Comment: you are great. Using getApplicationContext() is working. I wish google have done it so.

Comment: as LianYong pointed out, I had to change the context to getApplicationContext() for both: registerReceiver(apiManager.getBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter(ACTION)); and GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(getApplicationContext());

Comment: @Giorgio As the answer states, the problem was using different contexts, the application context should be used for all GCM actions.

Comment: vote +1 you are great but can you enhance the answer further ? some one can help improve the answer EDIT

Comment: If you need a improved answer I would recommend reading up on contexts in Android. If you only want a short and dirty fix: only use getApplicationContext() or context.getApplicationContext() in all GCM interactions (so never use the "this" variable).

Answer (score 8):

Another way.

```
GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(getApplicationContext());
```