# GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing Google Cloud messaging in my app and was provoked to add this : `GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);`, otherwise giving exception. But my confusion is that if I use `GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);` in `onDestroy()` of an activity , will the `GCMRegistrar` try again if some error occur for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here:

[GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(context) crashing, Receiver not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935680/gcmregistrar-ondestroycontext-crashing-receiver-not-registered)

Use getApplicationContext() instead of this (i.e. activity's context). Works for me. :D