# Eclipse android LogCat: GCMRegistrar: saving regId on app error

Tags: android, save, google-cloud-messaging

I can not figure this out, in one of my test apps I get an error when closing the app.

In LogCat I see the handleRegistration long code as ok, in blue text but some lines futher after saving regId on app the registration code is in red text.

Someone know why?

In another app, at the same emulator, it does not happen but I can not find the solution.

EDIT

You are right, sorry, this is LogCat output:

```
10-26 12:22:11.383: I/dalvikvm(754): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-26 12:22:11.539: I/dalvikvm(754): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-26 12:22:11.644: I/dalvikvm(754): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-26 12:22:11.718: I/dalvikvm(754): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-26 12:22:11.873: D/GCMRegistrar(754): resetting backoff for nl.easy.gcmnotification
10-26 12:22:11.883: V/GCMRegistrar(754): Registering app nl.easy.gcmnotification of senders 182xxxxxx601
10-26 12:22:12.153: I/dalvikvm(754): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-26 12:22:12.163: I/dalvikvm(754): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-26 12:22:12.445: D/gralloc_goldfish(754): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-26 12:22:13.843: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(754): onReceive: 
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
10-26 12:22:13.843: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(754): GCM IntentService class: nl.easy.gcmnotification.GCMIntentService
10-26 12:22:13.853: V/GCMBaseIntentService(754): Acquiring wakelock
10-26 12:22:13.864: V/GCMBaseIntentService(754): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-182537982601-1
10-26 12:22:13.953: E/GCMRegistrar(754): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
10-26 12:22:13.953: V/GCMRegistrar(754): Registering receiver
10-26 12:22:13.953: D/GCMBaseIntentService(754): handleRegistration: registrationId = APAxxxxxx8Kg, error = null, unregistered = null (IN COLOR BLUE)
10-26 12:22:13.953: D/GCMRegistrar(754): resetting backoff for nl.easy.gcmnotification
10-26 12:22:13.964: V/GCMRegistrar(754): Saving regId on app version 1
10-26 12:22:13.973: E/(754): registration id : APAxxxxxx8Kg (IN COLOR RED)
10-26 12:22:13.973: V/GCMBaseIntentService(754): Releasing wakelock
(WHEN SHUTTING DOWN APP)
10-26 12:22:35.033: V/GCMRegistrar(754): Unregistering receiver
10-26 12:22:35.033: D/AndroidRuntime(754): Shutting down VM
10-26 12:22:35.033: W/dalvikvm(754): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {nl.easy.gcmnotification/nl.easy.gcmnotification.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@412bc5c0
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3112)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3130)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1180)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@412bc5c0
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:628)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1066)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:354)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(GCMRegistrar.java:266)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at nl.easy.gcmnotification.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:49)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:4629)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3099)
10-26 12:22:35.155: E/AndroidRuntime(754):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post logcat or code. How can we help you otherwise?

Comment: Sorry, I edit the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by restarting eclipse and clean/rebuild the project... Strange but true!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code used for destroying the activity ?

I think your problem is the same as this one :
[GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(context) crashing, Receiver not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935680/gcmregistrar-ondestroycontext-crashing-receiver-not-registered)

Another potential issue : Did you declare the service in your manifest ?